# Add covariates to times series model using tbats

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting

**I want to predict the energy consumption every day +1.**

Exemple: using the data over the past 3 months, I want to predit the energy consumption of the day after.

Thus, I use a training set that ranges from [today- 3 months : today] and a test set that is basically the day after.

In my data set I have a consumption data every 15 minutes as well as meteorogical data such as the nebulosity and the temperature.

I then set the parameters for the seasonality:

```
## a data every 15 minutes
data.in.day <- 4*24
data.in.week <- 4*24*7
```

I use the library **forecast** to make prediction with the model based on the training set. I need to use the function **msts** to transform my data as times series because of the time interval that is too small for **ts**.

```
library(forecast)

   x <- train$Consumption
   x <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(data.in.day, data.in.week))
   fit <- tbats(x)
   fc <- forecast(fit, h=data.in.day)
```

Is there any way that I can add covariates (nebulosity, temperature) to the model?

Comment: Have you try to call `xts` on your data frame to convert it to time series object? Did you try to `cbind` you columns?

Comment: No, tbats does not handle covariates for technical reasons. Try the fasster package: https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/fasster

Comment: Thank you @RobHyndman , I am going to try the fasster package which looks great.